# Creating Launch Screen.xib for iOS8 ( ... iOS11, Swift 4 and LaunchScreen.storyboard )

Tags: swift3, ios8, storyboard, interface-builder, ios11

I've just found out that in order to be able to have the description for your app in the app store say "This app is optimized for iPhone 6, and iPhone 6 Plus." you need to use a launch XIB or storyboard file for your launch images (per [Apple][1]).

So, I've created a new Launch Screen xib and now I'm a little but since I usually do everything in code and don't use interface builder. I've deleted the default label that is inserted and dropped a `UIImageView` into the view. Now I'm wondering how would I:

1) Tell the `UIImageView` to resize to the size of whatever screen it's on

2) Tell the UIImageView to pick ImageA if a 3.5 inch screen is running the app or the ImageB if a 4 inch screen is running the app etc. etc.

Essentially, I'm just trying to get the launch .xib to mimic the behavior of how the launch screen works normally. Would appreciate it if anyone could provide some assistance on this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You make use of autolayout and give the imageview a fullscreen appearance (distance to top, bottom, left and right equals 0). This would however result in a clipping of the image for certain screen sizes, what you may not want. So you might want to consider (2)
2. You place the launch screen image into an asset catalog and just put different images into the different size classes.

Comment: Thanks. Just a warning, when using an asset catalog to supply the image of the UIImageView in the LaunchScreen.xib, don't link to a "launch image" set of images, that won't work. Just do a normal set of images.

Comment: If you are using the simulator to test, you may find that setting the 5.5" and 4.7" images on the LaunchImage asset group in the asset catalog will not cause any changes. This is because the asset catalog can be cached between builds. To ensure a clean run 
"Reset content and settings..." in the simulator menu and do a clean of your project before running it.

Comment: This can also be archieved by cleaning the build and simply deleting the app from the simulator.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer useful.

The old steps in short for creating the LaunchScreen **xib for iOS 8** are **below** the new steps.

With reference to **XCode 9, Swift 3 or Swift 4 and LaunchScreen.storyboard** following are the new steps.

First step is to create two images for Portrait and landscape mode splash ( png or jpeg ) in your favorite graphic software. ( If your app only support Portrait mode, you may skip Landscape mode image and settings. )

Portrait mode image :-

Create a 'splash-portrait' image with your own full background for size of "width 1125 x height 2436". Note that the background will clip on various sizes of devices.

Whichever info, graphic, you do not wish to be clipped should be created on center of above image in the size of "width 1125 x height **1471**". This should always be in center of above full image.

Landscape mode image :-

Create a 'splash-landscape' image with your own full background for size of "width 2436 x height 1125". Note that the background will clip on various sizes of devices.

Whichever info, graphic, you do not wish to be clipped should be created on center of above image in the size of "width **860** x height 1125". This should always be in center of above full image.

Once both the images are ready, you may add it to xcassets or keep in resource.

Now go for the following steps.

1) "LaunchScreen storyboard" is already created with the new project. Open it.

2) Add an Image View on the view.

3) Set the above saved 'splash-portrait' image to image view source.

4) Set Image view 'Content mode' of Image as "Aspect Fill".

5) Add 4 constraints of Image View for Top, Bottom, Trailing and Leading to Superview.

This is done for the **portrait** mode app splash.

For **landscape** mode support, do the following extra steps. [( you may refer full answer by @Sakiboy at 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46089856/2641380 )](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46089856/2641380)

6) Click the + button next to the Image view source that you set up in step 3.

7) From the pop-up that is now displayed select Regular for both the Width and Height selectors. This is specifying a new adaptive set for iPads that are in landscape. A new image source field will appear with the title wR hR. Add the 'splash-landscape' image to the wR hR Image source field so the storyboard knows to use a different image when in landscape.

8) Now we need to add support for the 'iphone plus' devices when in landscape. So click the + button next to the Image source field again.

9) This time select compact for the height and regular for the width selectors. This is specifying a new adaptive set for “iPhone plus” devices that are in landscape. A new image source field will appear with the title wR hC.

10) Add the “splash-landscape” image to the wR hC Image source field so the storyboard knows to use a different image when in landscape on an “iPhone plus device”.

As iPad devices are "Regular for both the Width and Height", We will see 'splash-landscape' image in iPad for both portrait and landscape mode. Width 860 for displayable content in 'splash-landscape' image will show full content in both portrait and landscape mode.

**The old steps in short for creating the LaunchScreen xib for iOS 8.**

1) create a new "LaunchScreen xib" from new file --> user interface --> launch screen ( keep auto layout ON ).

2) Add an image view in the xib --> view (main view).

3) set splash image to it ( the image should not be in assets file ).

4) set image as "Aspect Fit" ( if required ).

5) you may also change the "view" (super view) background color as close to background color of image.

6) select the image view, click from menu - editor - pin - bottom space to super view.

7) this will show red error mark near "view" ( super view of image view ).

8) click on the error mark, you will see approximate two auto layout errors.

9) on clicking on the error you will find menu with auto fix the layout errors.

10) on fixing the errors, you will find total four "Constraints" with "vertical" and "horizontal" space between superview and image.

11) now you may test them in different devices or simulators.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can resize the image by setting constraint to the top, bottom, leading and trailing edges of the superview. Just click the imageview and select Editor->Pin the top context menu. You can also set the aspects of the UIImageView by clicking it and setting it to for instance "Aspect Fit". Make sure the ImageView covers the whole screen before setting the constraints, or else you would have to modify the contstraints.

To set different images for different screen sizes, I would guess you have to create a class and modify to the viewWillAppear method to load an appropriate image

Good luck!
Erik

Answer (score 1):

Create a **new file**. Under **User Interface** select View. After, you can name your xib LaunchScreen and you can test it out by adding a label with something like “Test Launch” and run the app. You should see the launch screen appear!

Answer (score 0):

The Launch xib can't have a customized class since your app didn't launch when it is displayed. 
What I ended up doing is:

1. use sizing class feature
2. Create 3 UI images (one per sizing class)
3. Use auto layout with constrains which apply to each sizing class

So when you display one type of device the width and hight constrains of the other two UIImageView are set to 0